# Getting skype status from Javascript/Node

Tags: node.js, api, sdk, electron, skype

So I've been looking around for answers but haven't been able to find any up to date solutions to my problem. So my use case is pretty simple, I want to be able to check the online status of a list of users at my organisation using Skype for Business. Opening chats with them is simple enough, but actually getting the online status has shown to be a challenge.

I've been looking into the SDK but it seems a bit over the top for my use case, and I haven't been able to get web ticket authentication working (I'm implementing this in an Electron app). Even if I got that far, would I have to make an account with specifically only the contacts I need added and use that as authentication?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but it seems like the SDK/API is a bit over my level and I'm missing something. Do I need to add in my own server middleware between the node/electron-app and their API or something similar maybe?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe its an old version but have you looked into this?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/getpresencedataofacontact

Comment: some other example at github. its a plugin for sharepoint. 
 but its js/ts in node so it should be easy to figure out. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/js-skype-status

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll be looking into them today, they seem a lot more promising than what I've found.

Comment: Great.  let us know your solution please.  maybe it can help out others.